# How does one scrape a page like this?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

This is just an example page. This page sends very little HTML and seems to build most of its page information in a way that put together by the client's browser.

https://www.resto-in.fr/plandusite

Scrapy apparently is unable to see anything the way the browser does. I'm wondering how I can get scrapy to see what the browser sees.

Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because before asking you should try something and then come here and ask what is not working. Providing code is a vital part of a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are encountering here is called AJAX. Which basically means javascript downloads some stuff behind the scenes. Scrapy spiders do not execute javascript so you need to reverse engineer those calls yourself.

To do that:
If you open up the `network` tab in your favorite browser inspector(i.e. firebug)
You'll notice that when you are loading the website the javascript behind the scenes is opening some pages and downloading some stuff. In this case this page is downloading whole sitemap from: https://api.resto-in.com/api/v2/sitemap/1.json

You can see that here:
[image: inspector]

So this request returns json content with pretty much all of the data you are looking for.

More lazy alternative would be - to have a browser simulator like [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) to retrieve and execute javascript to load the page and then pass the source code to scrapy for crawling.

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: @DrewSSP Your welcome, I've also edited the answer to include a bit of info about alternative approach using `splash` to render the javascript for scrapy to crawl.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like Selenium or PhantomJS?  These will allow you to run a web browser in a programmable way, and then the Javascript/client pieces will all run just as when you browse manually.  If you are just pulling HTML and Javascript into Python's memory, for example, Python cannot execute that Javascript as your browser does, and depending on the site, 99% of the interaction may happen in that Javascript.

While going to the network tab in "developer tools" or Firebug might give you a hint as to what requests are being made, it may not be the best solution all the time.  For example, some sites fire off dozens of little AJAX requests in order to facilitate a minor interaction on their site (because they are doing logging, analytics, advertising, real-time notifications etc), and the request URLs can be (sometimes intentionally) cryptic or complicated.  You may not be able to figure out what each URL and parameter actually does, but you *may* realize that scrolling down a little bit and clicking on "next" arrow gets the pictures you want to show up on the screen.

Some sites also try to prevent scraping from non-browsers (to try and limit blatant harvesting of their data and keep usage more towards humans).  They will embed little "beacons" in client-side code, and if those beacons don't end up associating with your other requests, they will block your IP.  There should almost always be ways around these things, but it makes it more difficult.

Other things like cookies or HTML-5 storage are an additional concern.